# How to get current user ip address in Linux

Tags: linux

If a client connects to a Linux server with telnet or ssh, are there any commands for the client in this Linux server to find out his ip address that used to connect the server?

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough privileges, you can use ifconfig for discover your IP server:

```
iver $> ifconfig eth0
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (No such file or directory). Limited output.
iver $> ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:x0:ax:0x:xx
      inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: ::::/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:129311086 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:190083420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:20506219852 (19.0 GiB)  TX bytes:202398831699 (188.4 GiB)
      Interrupt:27 Base address:0xa000
```

But if you want to know about client ip the command pinky is the option:

```
iver $> pinky
Login    Name                 TTY      Idle   When             Where
iver                          pts/0           2012-10-12 08:50 200.xxx.xxx.001
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the man pages for the commands `w`, `who` and `finger`.

Answer (score 0):

Try command `pinky`

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pinky.htm